# Finding and replacing XML data inside tags using Python and Element Tree

Tags: python, xml, tree, element

Firstly I am very new to python and know very little. Yet have been tasked with making this programme so am thankful for any help.

I need to anonymise data inside in an XML file. This will include changing multiple tags to NULL.

I am first trying to use python with element tree to replace DateOfBirth data. I need the Date of birth tag to be replaced with NULL

This is a snippet of the XML file with one of the MOCK data of learners included. This includes 1 learner, There will be from 1-1000 learners normally and all values will need to be changed to NULL throughout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Please note that this file is properly formed, and serves as an example of a file that will load into the ILR DC system.  The data is anonymised and does not refer to a real-world provider, learning delivery or learner.  Based on the ILR specification, version 2, dated April 2018-->
<Message xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="ESFA/ILR/2018-19" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="ESFA/ILR/2018-19">
    <Header>
        <CollectionDetails>
            <Collection>ILR</Collection>
            <Year>1819</Year>
            <FilePreparationDate>2018-01-07</FilePreparationDate>
        </CollectionDetails>
        <Source>
            <ProtectiveMarking>OFFICIAL-SENSITIVE-Personal</ProtectiveMarking>
            <UKPRN>99999999</UKPRN>
            <SoftwareSupplier>SupplierName</SoftwareSupplier>
            <SoftwarePackage>SystemName</SoftwarePackage>
            <Release>1</Release>
            <SerialNo>01</SerialNo>
            <DateTime>2018-06-26T11:14:05</DateTime>
            <!-- This and the next element only appear in files generated by FIS -->
            <ReferenceData>Version5.0, LARS 2017-08-01</ReferenceData>
            <ComponentSetVersion>1</ComponentSetVersion>
        </Source>
    </Header>
    <SourceFiles>
        <!-- The SourceFiles group only appears in files generated by FIS -->
        <SourceFile>
            <SourceFileName>ILR-LLLLLLLL1819-20180626-144401-01.xml</SourceFileName>
            <FilePreparationDate>2018-06-26</FilePreparationDate>
            <SoftwareSupplier>Software Systems Inc.</SoftwareSupplier>
            <SoftwarePackage>GreatStuffMIS</SoftwarePackage>
            <Release>1</Release>
            <SerialNo>01</SerialNo>
            <DateTime>2018-06-26T11:14:05</DateTime>
        </SourceFile>
    </SourceFiles>
    <LearningProvider>
        <UKPRN>99999999</UKPRN>
    </LearningProvider>
    <!-- 16 yr old learner undertaking full time 16-19 (excluding apprenticeships) funded programme -->
    <Learner>
        <LearnRefNumber>16Learner</LearnRefNumber>
        <PMUKPRN>87654321</PMUKPRN>
        <CampId>1234ABCD</CampId>
        <ULN>1061484016</ULN>
        <FamilyName>Smith</FamilyName>
        <GivenNames>Jane</GivenNames>
        <DateOfBirth>1999-02-27</DateOfBirth>
        <Ethnicity>31</Ethnicity>
        <Sex>F</Sex>
        <LLDDHealthProb>2</LLDDHealthProb>
        <Accom>5</Accom>
        <PlanLearnHours>440</PlanLearnHours>
        <PlanEEPHours>100</PlanEEPHours>
        <MathGrade>NONE</MathGrade>
        <EngGrade>D</EngGrade>
        <PostcodePrior>BR1 7SS</PostcodePrior>
        <Postcode>BR1 7SS</Postcode>
        <AddLine1>The Street</AddLine1>
        <AddLine2>ToyTown</AddLine2>
        <LearnerFAM>
            <LearnFAMType>LSR</LearnFAMType>
            <LearnFAMCode>55</LearnFAMCode>
        </LearnerFAM>
        <LearnerFAM>
            <LearnFAMType>EDF</LearnFAMType>
            <LearnFAMCode>2</LearnFAMCode>
        </LearnerFAM>
        <LearnerFAM>
            <LearnFAMType>MCF</LearnFAMType>
            <LearnFAMCode>3</LearnFAMCode>
        </LearnerFAM>
        <LearnerFAM>
            <LearnFAMType>FME</LearnFAMType>
            <LearnFAMCode>2</LearnFAMCode>
        </LearnerFAM>
        <LearnerFAM>
            <LearnFAMType>PPE</LearnFAMType>
            <LearnFAMCode>2</LearnFAMCode>
        </LearnerFAM>
        <!-- Employment status record is not required for full time 16-19 (excluding apprenticeships) funded learners  -->
        <!-- 16-19  (excluding apprenticeships) funded study programme -->
        <LearningDelivery>
            <LearnAimRef>50022246</LearnAimRef>
            <AimType>5</AimType>
            <AimSeqNumber>1</AimSeqNumber>
            <LearnStartDate>2015-09-14</LearnStartDate>
            <LearnPlanEndDate>2016-07-02</LearnPlanEndDate>
            <FundModel>25</FundModel>
            <DelLocPostCode>BR1 3RL</DelLocPostCode>
            <CompStatus>1</CompStatus>
            <SWSupAimId>cb5f0d25-cff4-4ea0-92f5-99378cce306d</SWSupAimId>
            <LearningDeliveryFAM>
                <LearnDelFAMType>SOF</LearnDelFAMType>
                <LearnDelFAMCode>107</LearnDelFAMCode>
            </LearningDeliveryFAM>
        </LearningDelivery>
        <LearningDelivery>
            <LearnAimRef>50023408</LearnAimRef>
            <AimType>4</AimType>
            <AimSeqNumber>2</AimSeqNumber>
            <LearnStartDate>2015-02-14</LearnStartDate>
            <LearnPlanEndDate>2016-07-15</LearnPlanEndDate>
            <FundModel>25</FundModel>
            <DelLocPostCode>BR2 7UP</DelLocPostCode>
            <CompStatus>3</CompStatus>
            <LearnActEndDate>2015-04-01</LearnActEndDate>
            <WithdrawReason>98</WithdrawReason>
            <Outcome>3</Outcome>
            <SWSupAimId>c243182a-30af-4879-8f68-3eac708e6bb3</SWSupAimId>
            <LearningDeliveryFAM>
                <LearnDelFAMType>SOF</LearnDelFAMType>
                <LearnDelFAMCode>107</LearnDelFAMCode>
            </LearningDeliveryFAM>
        </LearningDelivery>
    </Learner>
```

**My current code:**

```
import os 
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et 

base_path  = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

xml_file = os.path.join(base_path, "ILR_mock_data.xml") 

tree = et.parse(xml_file) 

# root = tree.getroot()

# for child in root:
#     print(child.tag, child.attrib)

#for child in root:
#    for element in child:
#        print(element.tag, ":", element.text)


tree.find('Learner/DateOfBirth').text = 'NULL'

tree.wrtie("ILR_Aoned_output.xml")
```

**ERROR CODE:**

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jkay/Desktop/Anon Tool RCU/RCU MOCK TOOL (Anonamising).py", line 20, in <module>
    tree.find('Learner/DateOfBirth').text = 'NULL'
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I expect the programme to run through the XML file and return a new file with all Date Of Births replaced with NULL

Thanks for any help.

Comment: May be use regex?

Comment: For example, `result = re.sub(r"<DateOfBirth>(.*?)<\/DateOfBirth>", 'NULL', import)` where import - your file

Comment: I will look more into regex now. I did stumble into it as a solution when researching potential solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) looks like the solution you're looking for here. It's a library built specifically for parsing HTML and XML files (though [you'll maybe have to also install some parsers](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser).

Applied to your use case:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("my_file.xml", "r") as infile:
    xml_text = infile.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_text, 'xml')

# replace all DateOfBirth tag contents with NULL
for dob_tag in soup.find_all("DateOfBirth"):
    dob_tag.string = "NULL"

# output and save modified file
with open("my_file_edited.xml", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(soup.prettify())
```

As a bonus, you can also adapt the library to easily replace other tags, or do more complex/conditional modifications. The tool has pretty good documentation.

Comment: Thanks for this. Will definitely look more into it more. The option to do more conditional modifications was what drew me to element tree in the first place.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Had to spend a while fixing my Python install to get PIP and bs4 working properly. But the code has worked as intended.

Answer (score 0):

See below (with a simplified version of your XML)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<r>  <Learner>
        <LearnRefNumber>16Learner</LearnRefNumber>
        <PMUKPRN>87654321</PMUKPRN>
        <CampId>1234ABCD</CampId>
        <ULN>1061484016</ULN>
        <FamilyName>Smith</FamilyName>
        <GivenNames>Jane</GivenNames>
        <DateOfBirth>1999-02-27</DateOfBirth>
        <Ethnicity>31</Ethnicity>
        <Sex>F</Sex>
        <LLDDHealthProb>2</LLDDHealthProb>
        <Accom>5</Accom>
        <PlanLearnHours>440</PlanLearnHours>
        <PlanEEPHours>100</PlanEEPHours>
        <MathGrade>NONE</MathGrade>
        <EngGrade>D</EngGrade>
        <PostcodePrior>BR1 7SS</PostcodePrior>
        <Postcode>BR1 7SS</Postcode>
        <AddLine1>The Street</AddLine1>
        <AddLine2>ToyTown</AddLine2>
        <LearnerFAM>
            <LearnFAMType>LSR</LearnFAMType>
            <LearnFAMCode>55</LearnFAMCode>
        </LearnerFAM>
        <LearnerFAM>
            <LearnFAMType>EDF</LearnFAMType>
            <LearnFAMCode>2</LearnFAMCode>
        </LearnerFAM>
        <LearnerFAM>
            <LearnFAMType>MCF</LearnFAMType>
            <LearnFAMCode>3</LearnFAMCode>
        </LearnerFAM>
        <LearnerFAM>
            <LearnFAMType>FME</LearnFAMType>
            <LearnFAMCode>2</LearnFAMCode>
        </LearnerFAM>
        <LearnerFAM>
            <LearnFAMType>PPE</LearnFAMType>
            <LearnFAMCode>2</LearnFAMCode>
        </LearnerFAM>
        <!-- Employment status record is not required for full time 16-19 (excluding apprenticeships) funded learners  -->
        <!-- 16-19  (excluding apprenticeships) funded study programme -->
        <LearningDelivery>
            <LearnAimRef>50022246</LearnAimRef>
            <AimType>5</AimType>
            <AimSeqNumber>1</AimSeqNumber>
            <LearnStartDate>2015-09-14</LearnStartDate>
            <LearnPlanEndDate>2016-07-02</LearnPlanEndDate>
            <FundModel>25</FundModel>
            <DelLocPostCode>BR1 3RL</DelLocPostCode>
            <CompStatus>1</CompStatus>
            <SWSupAimId>cb5f0d25-cff4-4ea0-92f5-99378cce306d</SWSupAimId>
            <LearningDeliveryFAM>
                <LearnDelFAMType>SOF</LearnDelFAMType>
                <LearnDelFAMCode>107</LearnDelFAMCode>
            </LearningDeliveryFAM>
        </LearningDelivery>
        <LearningDelivery>
            <LearnAimRef>50023408</LearnAimRef>
            <AimType>4</AimType>
            <AimSeqNumber>2</AimSeqNumber>
            <LearnStartDate>2015-02-14</LearnStartDate>
            <LearnPlanEndDate>2016-07-15</LearnPlanEndDate>
            <FundModel>25</FundModel>
            <DelLocPostCode>BR2 7UP</DelLocPostCode>
            <CompStatus>3</CompStatus>
            <LearnActEndDate>2015-04-01</LearnActEndDate>
            <WithdrawReason>98</WithdrawReason>
            <Outcome>3</Outcome>
            <SWSupAimId>c243182a-30af-4879-8f68-3eac708e6bb3</SWSupAimId>
            <LearningDeliveryFAM>
                <LearnDelFAMType>SOF</LearnDelFAMType>
                <LearnDelFAMCode>107</LearnDelFAMCode>
            </LearningDeliveryFAM>
        </LearningDelivery>
    </Learner></r>
'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
dob_lst = root.findall('.//Learner/DateOfBirth')
for dob in dob_lst:
  dob.text = 'NULL'
ET.dump(root)
```

Comment: Can you try to run your code on OP's actual xml? I'm getting some errors when I try that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find all the elements `DateOfBirth` and replace each one:

```
for element in tree.findall('.//Learner/DateOfBirth'):
    element.text = 'NULL'
```

Comment: Thank you for this. The code runs and I get a new XML file in the intended location, but the XML file DateOfBirth has not changed.

Comment: Try to replace the last line by : `tree.write(open('ILR_Aoned_output.xml', 'wb'))`